# Not able to find admin username for Roundcube by Bitnami

Tags: roundcube, bitnami

After deploying  Roundcube by Bitnami  I am looking for admin username. This is the username in the deployment page. "Admin user: Use a GMail account by default" and the username is not admin. What does it mean how could I login the roundcube with admin user?
This is the deployment page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

roundcube does not have an administrative user. Administration is done by modifying the configuration file. The authentication for regular users is handled by the configured mail server.

Comment: So what is that administrator password in the deployment page for? If so I think I should connect by ssh and do some configuration would you put some link to help me start configuring users and and other settings since I could not enter mysql as well since there were no password provided for that as well.

Comment: I don't know what deployment page you are referring to. I've been using roundcube for many years, I've never seen an administrator account. There is no such account mentioned in the documentation. If it's something special by bitnami (I'm not familiar with this) it should be documented there.

Comment: The only admin user that is mentioned in the bitnami roundcube documentation is the MySQL admin user.

Comment: I edited the question and included the deployment page from Google cloud. Is MySQL admin user is the same root or does it have a different name?

Comment: The mysql admin account is root. It's all documented: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/roundcube/

Comment: Oh thanks finally I logged in to phpmyadmin with root and the admin password provided would not it be easier to write these clear in the deployment page instead of those deceiving sentences.